# Boost Python and Cmake with Ubuntu and Python3.5

Tags: python, ubuntu, cmake, python-3.5, boost-python

I'm having issues getting Boost Python to compile with Cmake. Everything works fine when compiled manually. Here is how I set everything up and ran it :

- Install python 3.5 :

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python3-dev
  ```
- Download the lastest version of Boost from http://www.boost.org/
- Run bootstrap with correct flags :

  ```
  ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python3.5
  ```
- Compile Boost in directory :

  ```
  ./b2
  ```
- Install Boost headers to /usr/local/include and Boost libs to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

  ```
  sudo ./b2 install
  ```
- Compile example with proper flags :

  ```
  g++ greet_binding.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/local/include -lboost_python-py35 -lpython3.5m -o greet.so -shared -fPIC
  ```
- Start Python interpreter :

  ```
  $ python3

  import greet

  greet.say_greeting("Foo")

  Hello, Foo!
  ```

greet_binding.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace bp = boost::python;

void say_greeting(const char* name)
{
        cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(greet)
{
        bp::def("say_greeting", say_greeting);
}
```

However, when I try to set up a simple CmakeLists.txt file to compile it, I get an error when importing the compiled .so from Python.

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.3 )
project ( boost-python-3.5-examples )

set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} \
-g -std=c++14 \
-I/usr/include/python3.5m \
-I/usr/local/include \
-lboost_python-py35 \
-lpython3.5m \
-fPIC" )

add_library( greet SHARED greet_binding.cpp )
```

This compiles fine, then I start the python interpreter in the build directory :

```
$ python3

import libgreet

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/james/Programming/boost-python-3.5-examples/build/libgreet.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: boost has its own build system, which I used.  The trick is you have to tell it where to find your python install, before it links in the python lib, which would be required before it can build boost_python. Oh wait, you said ubuntu -- you can install that with the package manager.  Is it an issue with building a specific version of boost python, with a specific version of python?

Comment: Did you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH when compilling manually?

Comment: Did you figure out?