# Build boost for python 3.5 under Ubuntu 18

Tags: python-3.x, boost, build

I installed `boost` using `apt-get`. Programs see it fine when doing a `bootstrap`:

```
idf@ubvm:$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep Version
Version: 1.65.1.0ubuntu1
```

All of them are found:

```
idf@ubvm:$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

When linking a program, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-py35
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
```

So I am trying to build `boost` 1.69 from source, to support `python` 3.5.

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python            /usr/bin/python2-config  /usr/bin/python3.6          /usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/python2           /usr/bin/python3         /usr/bin/python3.6-config   /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python3.5       /usr/bin/python3.6m         /usr/bin/python3m-config
/usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3.5m      /usr/bin/python3.6m-config  /usr/bin/python-config
```

When I run `bootstrap`, it is detecting `python 2.7`

```
idf@ubvm:~/Downloads/boost_1_69_0$ ./bootstrap.sh
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/src/engine/bin.linuxx86_64/b2
Detecting Python version... 2.7
Detecting Python root... /usr
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... /usr
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    ./b2
```

I then did a `locate` after installing `./b2 install`:

```
idf@ubvm:$ locate libboost_python
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.65.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py36.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py36.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3-py36.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3-py36.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3-py36.so.1.65.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3.so
```

How do I tell the system to also build the `python` 3.5(m) libraries as well as the 2.7?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but that question was not answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491536/boost-python-and-cmake-with-ubuntu-and-python3-5